# NSTableView with Plus and Minus buttons

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

How can I do something like that?

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't find any appropriate object in the Interface Builder library.

Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTableView with +/- buttons like in System Preferences using only Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586313/nstableview-with-buttons-like-in-system-preferences-using-only-interface-bui)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best way that i found is to use NSSegmentedControl.

after you dragged it on the canvas, you should configure its style:

```
Style: Small Square
Mode:  Select Momentary
```

looks better. Now use "image" field to set **NSAddTemplate** and **NSRemoveTemplate**. Make sure that label field is empty.

Ok, we have "*+*", "*-*" and one empty segment. To prevent the latest one to be selected by the user, select it from **Segment:** pop up and turn off **Enabled** check box (located next to **State:** label).

And lastly, what we have to do is set **width** of first two segments to make them square.

1. Go to *Size inspector*
2. Select **Segment 0**
3. Turn off "**Fixed**" checkbox (segment should immediately autoresize to fit image)
4. Select **Segment 1** and repeat number 3
5. Now as you resize control, only last segment will change width
6. Put it at the bottom of your table view and resize as well.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: I like that better than the accepted answer because it keeps everything together and I can disable the third segment without changing its appearance.  But how do you handle resizing of a window that stretches the control?

Comment: i used it in non-resizeable part of window. but as i know it's really challenging to get it resizing. if you will achieve that let me know by posting another answer and i'll vote up for u.

Comment: @JeremyP See second part of answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22586314/15809 ; you can mix a segmented control with a NSButton to get the ideal look, behavior and autoresizing.

Comment: FYI, it's no longer called Mode Select `None` but `Momentary`

Comment: @bithavoc, i'm no longer with with XCode / Cocoa and all.  feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 11):

**Update for OSX Yosemite**

I tried to achieve the same look as Mail.app has in the Accounts view (right window on my screenshot).

I did achieve the desired result by following the steps below:

1. Add a `NSSegmentedControl`
2. Add two segments and set the image to each:

   - `NSAddTemplate` for the `+` button
   - `NSRemoveTemplate` for the `-` button
3. Set the size of the segments to `fixed` and set the value to `32` pixels
4. The rectangle next to the buttons is a `NSButton` with the style `Gradient`.
5. The Button is enabled but **Refuses First Responder** is set to `true` so that it is not clickable.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

Use a NSButton with a gradient style, and for the images use the system provided NSAddTemplate and NSRemoveTemplate.

Comment: Nice, but when using multiple gradient buttons, disabling one of them breaks the look. Segmented control works better here, as disabling a single segment only dims the text or the image but does not change the background.

Answer (score 3):

One answer here suggests using gradient buttons, however these buttons cannot be disabled as this causes the background to change and thus breaks the look. Another one suggested using a segmented control, which is almost perfect but segmented controls don't support autoresizing, e.g. if the table width is dynamic. My suggestion is a combination of both. Use a segmented control for the actual buttons and a gradient button to fill the rest of the table width that now can also be dynamic if the button width is dynamic as well.

See my answer to a similar question (with screenshots):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586314/15809