# Add and remove buttons for NSTableView (Mac Interface Builder)

Tags: xcode, button, interface-builder

I'm trying to create something like that
[image: buttons]

but I can't find any guide or template. I found an old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706357/nstableview-with-plus-and-minus-buttons) but I can't follow the instructions (I can only make one button)

How can I make it work? I can't find it even in apple's documentation...

Thank you very much.