# What Cocoa Views and Controls Will Create Something like Part of the Network Prefs Display (Mac OS)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building an OSX app and want to create a set of controls similar to what's found at bottom of the standard Network Preferences configuration panel. I'm running into some layout problems that I wouldn't have expected.

[image]

These are my specific questions:

1. What contains the 3 buttons so there's similar shading all they way across the row where the buttons are positioned? In particular, what's causing the area without buttons to have shading?
2. How do you do this without getting a double border where the row of buttons meets up with the table?

I want to do this with an xib file. This may be incredibly simple, but I'm missing something I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I find that if you make a button with style "Gradient" and type "Momentary Change", then it looks like the other buttons but does not respond to clicks, so you can use that as the area after the last button.  (The `NSMomentaryChangeButton` is documented as changing the image and title when clicked, so if you don't use an image or title, nothing should change.)

If you check **Refuses First Responder** in the attributes inspector, then it will not be possible to highlight this blank button using Full Keyboard Access.

Ken Thomases also brings up the issue of the blank button being shown as a button to Accessibility.  One can fix that by using a subclass of `NSButtonCell` that has just one method:

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityIsIgnored
{
    return YES;
}
```

I think that's easier than writing a custom view.

As d00dle says, avoid double borders by slightly overlapping things.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the slack space to have the same background as the buttons, and since the buttons can change appearance from release to release of the OS, the best thing to do is to get the frameworks to draw it like it would the buttons.

Rather than using an actual button as JWWalker suggests, I have used a custom view that leverages `NSButtonCell` to draw the background. The advantage is that you can be sure there's no chance of getting undesirable behavior. For example, a button could get focus (for users who have All Controls selected in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access) so that the user could Tab to it. Accessibility will report the presence of the button through VoiceOver. Etc.

Configure the button cell just like the buttons (set `buttonType` and `bezelStyle`). In the view's `-drawRect:` call `[buttonCell drawWithFrame:rect inView:self];`, where `rect` is similar to the frames of the buttons. Since one way to avoid double borders is to make the buttons larger than the view's bounds, you may need to do the same for `rect`. For example, you might want to use `NSInsetRect(self.bounds, -1, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are buttons... This can be accomplished with a custom view drawing border and the background "shading".

To avoid the double border where the table and the custom view meet you simply align it so they overlap by 1 point (pixel) or avoid drawing the top border in your custom view.

I don't know of any standard object capable of doing this.

Comment: But what's causing the last area after the third button to have shading?

Comment: That would be a custom draw in the view.