# Mac OS X UI: How to create plus & minus buttons?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, user-interface

In my current application, I would like to add plus & minus buttons like the ones you see all over the place on Mac OS X, e.g.

[image: Mac OS X UI plus minus buttons sample screenshot]

I know in general how to add buttons to a user interface, but these plus & minus buttons are so ubiquitous that I imagine Apple have coined a special term for them (like 'drawer' or 'sheet') and prepared a really simple way to add them.

Unfortunately, 'plus' and 'minus' seem to be too generic terms to yield useful Google results and I don't know what else to search for :-(

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706357/nstableview-with-plus-and-minus-buttons

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, in all the apps I've ever written, they're just two square buttons aligned carefully side-by-side.

The only trick is to use `NSAddTemplate` and `NSRemoveTemplate` when providing your buttons their images - these are system-provided images that will look like the ones in your screenshot.